# Google Analytics show account information

Tags: javascript, google-analytics, google-analytics-api

I have Server-side Authorized GA dashboard set up, and i have several websites on my google account I want to show on the top of the page google account info and site name, which is shown on my page.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to call the [`accountSummaries.list()`](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/config/mgmt/v3/mgmtReference/management/accountSummaries) method to get the information about the account.

See the [account explorer](https://ga-dev-tools.appspot.com/account-explorer/) for a demo with [source code](https://github.com/googleanalytics/ga-dev-tools).